# Git post-commit hook console log

Tags: git, gradle, sh

If I have a git post-commit hook which running a gradle build then how can I see the console log under the running?
For example compile.., test..
Thanks the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If gradle is printing to standard output you will see the log before the confirmation summary of commit.

Remember your `post-commit` hook has to be executable, otherwise it's not run.